# Kali Linux Gnome desktop shorcut

Tags: desktop, desktop-shortcuts

I am wondering how can I create a program ( e.g. VS Code) desktop shortcut on Kal Linux Gnome interface. So that I click the desktop shortcut and the program runs. Unfortunately, I cannot find this information anywhere in the system or the internet, anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a right click "Add to desktop"?

Comment: I don't have any option like that. When I right-click on any app shortcut in "show programs" section, the only options I have are "New Window" and "Add to favorites". And when I do the same with shortcut in "Favourites" section, I can choose "New Window" and "Delete from favourites".

Comment: Have you tried drag and drop from icons list and favorites menu?

Comment: of course, doesn't work either

Comment: Then try to make Applmage https://itsfoss.com/use-appimage-linux/